# how to serve an angular 6 app on an express server?

Tags: angular, express

My express server.js has this line

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/')));
```

That will serve up the angular app when users go to `/` but if the app has routes for example `/test` — the app will not show.

> Cannot GET /

So I am trying to rewrite the middleware but not having much luck. This is what i am trying.

```
app.get('*.*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/')));
```

How do I write the middleware so all `/*` routes will show the app?

Comment: have you used router link in the front end?

Comment: I dont understand

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that i needed middleware for the app then another for the routes

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/browser/')));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/browser/')));
```